# Why can't I name my ship "Spumious Hamster"?

Tags: sea-of-thieves

Been away from the game for a while, now I see we are buying our own ships and naming them.

I decided to name mine "Spumious Hamster", but the game says that name is unacceptable.

The naming rules are (verbatim):

- 20 characters maximum.
- Cannot contain any numbers.
- Cannot start or end with a space.
- Cannot use certain special characters.

Mine is 16 chars, has no numbers, doesn't start or end with a space, and uses no special characters (although we might not see eye-to-eye there).

What gives?

Comment: It very well could be a profanity filter kicking in, whether you meant it or not

Comment: I'm referring this question to our branch office in Intercourse, Pennsylvania.

Comment: Definitely looks like the Scunthorpe Problem